# How to Perform a Join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to print a list of accounts that are in 2 branches. Data is coming from 2 tables: account & branch. How do I get the db to print the customer id, account number and account type from the account table and branch name from the branch table? I figure there needs to be a JOIN command somewhere.

Comment: 1. We're going to need to see your table structures 2. What have you tried?

Comment: How's this question related to mysql-workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your field names, but you'd need something like this if you have branch_id on account:

```
SELECT account.cust_id, account.account_id, account.product_cd, branch.name INNER JOIN branch ON branch.id = account.branch_id FROM account
```

Or if you have account_id on branch:

```
SELECT account.cust_id, account.account_id, account.product_cd, branch.name INNER JOIN account ON branch.account_id = account.id FROM branch
```

Comment: SELECT cust_id, account_id, product_cd from account
SELECT name from branch where name = 'So. NH Branch' or name = 'Woburn Branch';

Answer (score 0):

This will work if assuming you have a field named "branch_id" on both tables.  Otherwise insert the linking field names.

```
SELECT  a.`customer id`, a.`account number`, a.`account type`, b.`branch name`

FROM    account AS a

        JOIN branch AS b
        ON a.branch_id = b.branch_id
```

You can remove the backticks (`) if your field names do not have spaces.